# Setter lens to act on a range of a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Given an array eg `[1..]` is there a way with lenses to double all the numbers in the range `[4,100]` so it becomes

```
1,2,3,8,10,12,14,16,...,200,101,102...
```

I am not very fluent with lenses but I feel like getters are the right tool for this.

Comment: Why not just use a map with an if statement in there? `map (\x -> if 4 <= x && x <= 100 then 2 * x else x)`?  Lenses are a sledgehammer for a very small nail here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> :m + Control.Lens Data.Ix
> (traverse . filtered (inRange (4, 7)) *~ 2) [1..10]
[1,2,3,8,10,12,14,8,9,10]
```

Note that this is probably violating the lens laws, and so may have unexpected behavior in larger code contexts -- one is supposed to be careful that the property passed to `filtered` is not violated by the updates performed!